# Error in increase the size of the foreground object using openCV and arcpy

Tags: opencv, arcpy, maxima

I have an image and would like to find the foreground objects and increase their size for later watershed segmentation using openCV. Firstly, I found the local maxima of the image (image gray1) with the window size is 7x7 using arcpy (local maxima is also the foreground objects). Then, I convert the raster image created into numpy array and use cv2.dilate to increase the size of foreground objects, but the result is not as expected. The following codes:

```
inRaster = Raster("gray1.jpg")
neighborhood = NbrCircle(7, "CELL")

# Execute FocalStatistics in arcpy to find local maxima
outFocalStatistics = FocalStatistics(inRaster, neighborhood, "MAXIMUM","")
outFocalStatistics.save("max7_1.tif")
outRaster = Raster("D:/Lien/Practice/TEST_CROWN_REGION/WATERSHED/max7_1.tif")
outCon = Con(inRaster == outRaster, inRaster, 0)
fore_ground = ExtractByAttributes(outCon, "Value >40")
#Convert fore_Ground to numpy array
fore_ground_np= arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(fore_ground)
fore_ground_8u = np.uint8(fore_ground_np)
disk=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
fore_ground1= cv2.dilate(fore_ground_np,disk, iterations=1)
```

[image: gray1]
   [image: fore_ground (local maxima)]
[image: fore_ground increased]

Comment: The maxima tag is used wrongly.